# How do you force Haskell's cabal-install program to ignore system libraries?

Tags: haskell, package, ghc, cabal

I'm trying to install the accelerate library from hackage, but it keeps giving me an error saying that my version of base package (4.15.1.0) is too new. Is there a way to force it to ignore the base package that's installed as a system-wide package, and instead download the correct version of the base package?

I'm using Manjaro Linux, ghc version 9.0.2, and cabal version 3.4.0.0. I can't seem to find any documentation on how to force it to ignore a system package. I've tried searching on https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/ , but it doesn't seem to mention it anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `base` package is always hard-fixed to the compiler version. The only way to switch `base` is to switch to a different GHC. That's easier with Stack than it is with Cabal-install – just select a snapshot that has a suitable `base` version (`lts-18.24` would do), and Stack will automatically install the corresponding compiler.

But it could well be that you *can* actually use `base-4.15`, and just `accelerate` has conservative dependency bounds. Try installing it with `--allow-newer=base`. If that works, give the maintainers a PR that the version bounds can be relaxed.

Comment: It's really quite easy with `cabal-install` these days (using `ghcup` to install GHC versions). Look up which version you need [on the Haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Base_package).